# How to convert byte to hex?

Tags: python, hex

I am needing to send some data over serial but before I send, I need to calculate the checksum using modulo 256. I can work out the checksum and display it as a hex value (in this case the checksum is `0xb3`) but it displays it as `0xb3` but I need it to be `\xb3` as I am sending other messages before it.

I have tried encoding, bytes and bytearray, but can not get it to send the hexadecimal value. It sends `'0xb3'` as a string.

```
def calculate_csum(message):
    message = b'\x60\x08\x46\x52\x41\x50\x5a\x45\x52\x31' #just temp
    j = 0
    for i in message:
        j = j + i

    csum  = hex(j % 256)
    csum = csum.encode("ascii")
    print(csum)
    full_string = message + csum
    print (full_string)
    return csum
```

The output of the full string is `b'\x08FRAPZER10xb3'` but if I hardcode it with `b'\x60\x08\x46\x52\x41\x50\x5a\x45\x52\x31\xb3'` I get `b'\x08FRAPZER1\xb3'` it works, so I need to drop the `0xb3` and replace it with `\xb3`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need to go through gyrations to convert `csum` to a string then back to a byte string, you want it as a single byte in the first place.

```
csum = bytes([j % 256])
```